# Cannot use an another property's Object into a foreach on CodeIgniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, object, foreach

I'm using a foreach to get the type of a question compared to the id of "T_Question" but there's always an unexpected error who say

> Trying to get property of non-object

If i do that without a for(each) and take the first array there is no problem but I have to get all names of my table "T_Question_Type" compared to each ID of my table "T Question"

```
        $output['questions'] = $this->question_model->get_all();

        foreach($output['questions'] as $key => $object){
        $id = $object->ID;
        $t_question_type = $this->fk_question_type_model->get_by('ID = ' . $id);
        $object->ID = $t_question_type->Type_Name;
```

Comment: Are you sure that `$t_question_type` is an object and not an array ? Could you `var_dump` it ?

Comment: when i var_dump $t_question_type that returns me :
'object(stdClass)#24 (2) { ["ID"]=> string(1) "1" ["Type_Name"]=> string(15) "Choix multiples" }' @roberto06

Comment: It should work then... What line does the PHP error refer to ?

Comment: This line : `$object->ID = $t_question_type->Type_Name;` @roberto06

Comment: And `$object` is also an object ? Is the `ID` index protected ?

Comment: show fk_question_type_model->get_by()..see what exactlty it returns...

Comment: `var_dump($object)`returns _object(stdClass)#22 (9) { ["ID"]=> string(1) "1" ["FK_Topic"]=> string(1) "3" ["FK_Question_Type"]=> string(1) "1"....._ and the ID is protected here `protected $protected_attributes = 'ID';` @roberto06

Comment: If the `ID` is protected, you can't set it directly with `$object->ID = 'some value';`, you have to create a `setID` function in your class file and use it with `$object->setID('some value');`